# add pure virtual function

Tags: c++, function

I'm working on my final project for school. This is what my teacher wants me to do to the code I wrote but I don't really understand it. Can some one help me out?  This is pretty much how the rest of my code is - I didn't want to put the whole thing up on account of it's too long.

"You don't have any classes, just function calls. If you create a Scene class that is abstract, make the RunScene() function pure virtual. Then you can create subclasses of Scene for Intro, Scene1, Scene2, and Scene3 and put the scene code in the appropriate RunScene() function for each. That would go a long way towards improving your structure."

```
void nichole() {
    int choice4;
    do {
    cout << "\t ----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\t ----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\t\n i really like nichole the best" << endl;
    cout << "\t\n Nichole it is What is her interst?" << endl;
    cout << "\t\n idk" << endl;
    cout << "\t\n What do you mean you dont know?" << endl;
    cout << "\t\n ive never really talked to her" << endl;
    cout << "\t\n Well then how is she your favorite?" << endl;
    cout << "\t\n because shes the prettiest lol" << endl;
    cout << "\t\n Of course she is bry. can you tell me anything about her?" << endl;
    cout << "\t\n shes a cheerleader" << endl;
    cout << "\t\n Perfect I can work with that" << endl;
    cout << "\t\n thank you :)" << endl;
    cout << "\t\n tomrow you have to ask her out on a date" << endl;
    cout << "\t\n what no way man shes way to hott" << endl;
    cout << "\t\n Then get beat up by your cousins giant boy friend then" << endl;
    cout << "\t\n ahh fine what do i say to her exactly ive never asked" << endl;
    cout << "\t out on a date before" << endl;
    cout << "\t\n Choose response:" << endl;
    cout << "\t 1.Ask her to the theater" << endl;
    cout << "\t\ 2.Ask her for a cup of coffee" << endl;
    cout << "\t\ 3.Ask her to a football game" << endl;
    cin >> choice4;

        if ((choice4== 1) && (choice4 = 2)) {
            cout << "\t\n are you sure" << endl;
            cout << "\t\n Yes im sure" << endl;
            cout << "\t\n ok if you say so" << endl;
            loose();
        }
        else if (choice4 = 3) {
            cout << "\t\n dude your a genius" << endl;
            cout << "\t\n I Know get back to me tomorow and let me know how it goes" << endl;
            loose();
        }
        else {
            cout << "Invalid choice" << endl;
        }
    }
    while ((choice4 != 1) && (choice4 != 2) && (choice4 != 3));
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: thanks for editing

Comment: Bjarne's C++ Programming and Principles would be a good read for this.

Comment: `choice4 = 2` isn't `choice4 == 2`. One is assignment that is always true, the other is a condition. Even if you did `if ((choice4== 1) && (choice4 == 2))` it still doesn't make sense since it can't be both 1 and 4 at the same time. I think you meant: `if (choice4 == 1 || choice4 == 2)` Is that what you're looking for? What's the question here?

Comment: Apparently, the code was homework and the student got some feedback on it that he doesn't understand.

Comment: he wants me to add classes that are pure virtual but I don't really understand that concept, all my code is voids like this one and then I added it to the main

Comment: I think he wants you to organize your code better in terms of object oriented programming taking advantage of inheritance. A virtual member function of a base class can be overridden by derived classes that also have a `RunScene` member function, but if you remove the keyword `virtual` from the base class then `RunScene` would use the base class's implementation.